# How do I turn on Out of Office (OOO) for Outlook 2010?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

How do I turn on the out of office reply with VBA in Office 2010?

I can only find answers for previous Office versions.

Ideally I want the code to disable when I open Outlook 2010 and enable when I close it.

---

```
Private Sub Test()

    Const PR_OOF_STATE = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x661D000B"
    Dim olkIS As Outlook.Store
    Dim olkPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
    
    For Each olkIS In Session.Stores
        If olkIS.ExchangeStoreType = olPrimaryExchangeMailbox Then
            Set olkPA = olkIS.PropertyAccessor
            olkPA.SetProperty PR_OOF_STATE, True
        End If
    Next
    
    Set olkIS = Nothing
    Set olkPA = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Store.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty` to set the `PR_OOF_STATE` MAPI property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x661D000B`) property to true to turn OOF on and false to turn it off.

If you want to explicitly set the OOF time range, you can only do that using EWS ([SetUserOofSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/setuseroofsettings-operation) operation). You would need to know the user credentials of course.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Dmitry. Sorry, how do I write this in VBA? I have a default out of office set which is fine, I just want to be able to turn it on and off using code.

Comment: As I mentioned above, you need to use Store.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty to set the PR_OOF_STATE property. Are you running into an error doing that?

Comment: I've added the code above. I don't get an error and it does seem to run, but it doesn't enable OOO. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, yes, it looks like Office 365 servers no longer set OOF on when PR_OOF_STATE is changed. So EWS is your only option...

Comment: Thanks again Dimitry. One more question, if I may: how do you use EWS? I've Googled it but I don't understand what application I would use to run it, as it doesn't appear to be VBA? Any advice or link to get me started would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think you'd be able to do that from VBA - maybe using XMLHTTPRequest object -see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeamsgdev/2011/11/30/using-exchange-web-services-from-vbscript-sending-a-message-with-attachment-example/ for an example.